# Why is my home made chocolate oily?

Tags: chocolate

I made chocolate using cacao butter, cacao powder, sugar (icing and granulated), and dried milk powder.

In addition to being too sweet (panicked and added too much icing and granulated sugar), and too grainy (I removed the cacao butter from heat and added the other ingredients), it taseted really oily.

Why was the chocolate oily?

I made the following errors:
1. Not properly measuring everything (I couldn't find a suitable recipe)
2. Removing the cacao butter from heat and then adding the other ingredients 
3. Not whisking the chocolate mixture 
4. Not pre mixing the dry ingredients
5. Not sticking to icing sugar

Comment: Is this a serious question? You seem to have done everything possible to avoid forming a stable emulsion (chocolate is an emulsion of cocoa solids and sugar dispersed in butter). It's no surprise it turned out oily.

Comment: @MarkWildon Unfortunately, yes, it is a serious question. Your comment would explain it. I am really bad chef, but wanted to attempt it never the less. Please could you explain how to achieve a stable emulsion? Thanks

Comment: I suggest you find a highly rated recipe on the web and follow it very closely. Making chocolate is a challenge.

Comment: While your question asked about a specific outcome (oily), I am still closing it as a duplicate of the previous question - even if you were to fix your mistakes, you would soon run into the fact that you can't make chocolate.

Comment: @rumtscho: I admit I have never tried, but note that this questioner is starting from cacao powder, not the beans. There are many highly rated recipes on the web for making chocolate from cocoa powder that suggest that people have found this a worthwhile exercise, even if the results won't have the smoothness of commercial chocolate.

Comment: It's easier to fix unknown problems if you fix all known problems first. Avoid making the same mistakes again that you've identified, then if you still have issues and don't know where you've gone wrong, ask a question about it.

Comment: Thank you @Kat, I will try not to make the same mistakes again.